# Determine whether S is a subspace of V, if yes find a basis and its dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So this here questions got me stuck for a bit:

> Determine whether S is a subspace of V, if yes find a basis and its
>   dimension. Let $S$ be the set of all 3x3 symmetric matrices in $V =
>  M_{3x3}$

And here's why: I checked the appropriate axioms and it turns out S is in fact a subspace of V, but my main problem is that before this exercise, to find a basis, I'd find the augmented matrix and solve it (RREF) and then determine the solution, but here I'm not sure if I can.

So I have an approach but not sure which if it works:

If I say for e.g.

Assume the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
    a &  b & c\\
    b & d & e\\ 
    c & e & f\\ \end{pmatrix}$

if det(A) $\neq 0$ => linearly independent => the basis exists.

$k_1\begin{pmatrix}
    a\\
    b\\ 
    c\\ \end{pmatrix}$
+ $k_2\begin{pmatrix}
    b\\
    d\\ 
    e\\ \end{pmatrix}$
+ $k_3\begin{pmatrix}
    c\\
    e\\ 
    f\\ \end{pmatrix} = 0; 
dim(S) = 3$

Please let me know how to go about this. Thank you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde it is the same question, but my approach was not explained there.

Comment: Your approach is explained in the duplicate. For example, the matrix with parameter $b$ is $E_{12}+E_{21}$ from the answer there, and for $a$ it is $\frac{1}{2}(2E_{11})=E_{11}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. The vector space $V$ is $9$-dimensional. How many of the $9$  entries can you specify independently in a $3 \times 3$ matrix and have it be symmetric. Clearly not all $9$.